# Parsing nested JSON in groovy

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I would like to parse the below nested JSON in Groovy and get the values of "it","ft","stg","prd" for each application and store in separate array.Can someone help please ?

```
    {
        "Application1": {
            "environments": {
                "it": [
                    "server1"
                ],
                "ft": [
                    "server2"
                ],
                "stg": [
                    "server3"
                ],
                "prd": [
                    "server4"
                ]
            },
            "war-path" : "/opt/tomcat/",
            "war-name" : "Application1"
        },
        "Application2": {
            "environments": {
                "it": [
                    "serverA"
                ],
                "ft": [
                    "serverB"
                ],
                "stg": [
                    "serverC"
                ],
                "prd": [
                    "serverD"
                ]
            },
            "war-path" : "/var/lib",
            "war-name" : "Application2"
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output something like below in separate list for each environment. Also the 1st level(Application1,Application2..) will be dynamic always

```
it = [server1,serverA]
ft = [server2,serverB]
stg = [server3, serverC]
prd = [server4,serverD]
```

**Updated:** After deriving expected answer with the inputs from Philip Wrage.

```
def projects = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}//${infrafile}"
def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson(projects)
def json_beauty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)
def envlist = ["it","ft","stg","prd"]
def fileListResult = []


for (envname in envlist) {
    servers=serverlist(json_beauty,envname)
    println(servers)
}

def serverlist(json_beauty,envname){
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def jsonMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(json_beauty)

    assert jsonMap instanceof Map
    jsonMap.each { appName, appDetails ->

        assert appDetails instanceof Map
        appDetails.environments.each { envName, servers ->
            for (items in servers{
                if (envName == "${envname}"){
                    fileListResult.add(items)
                }
            }
        }        
    }
    return fileListResult
}
```

Comment: Can you just use JsonSlurper and then first array would just be [Application1.it, Application1.ft ... Etc] and similar with Application 2

Comment: It would help if you showed exactly the output you want, exactly what you've tried, and exactly how that failed

Comment: Or if you want the text value, I guess it would be like [Application1.it[0], Application1.ft[0]..... ] Though I haven't tried this out, just a guess hence comment rather than answer

Comment: @Chris and tim_yates ..Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Chris, you can use the built-in [`JsonSlurper`](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) to parse the JSON and then navigate the parsed results as a `Map`.

In the following example I show how you can simply print the results to the console.  However, using this as a guide, you can see how to extract the data into whatever kind of data structure that suits your purpose.

Assume that you have the JSON in a `String` variable `jsonText`.  You may be pulling in from a file or an HTTP POST or whatever your app requires.  I used the following code to set this value for testing.

```
def jsonText = """
{
    "Application1": {
    "environments": {
        "it": [
                "server1"
        ],
        "ft": [
                "server2"
        ],
        "stg": [
                "server3"
        ],
        "prd": [
                "server4"
        ]
    },
    "war-path" : "/opt/tomcat/",
    "war-name" : "Application1"
},
    "Application2": {
    "environments": {
        "it": [
                "serverA"
        ],
        "ft": [
                "serverB"
        ],
        "stg": [
                "serverC"
        ],
        "prd": [
                "serverD"
        ]
    },
    "war-path" : "/var/lib",
    "war-name" : "Application2"
}
}
"""
```

The meat of the solution then follows.  Parse the JSON text into a `Map`, and then [iterate over the entries in that `Map`](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_iterating_on_maps), performing whatever operations you require.  The servers for each environment will already be contained within a [`List`](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Lists).

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonText)

assert jsonMap instanceof Map

jsonMap.each { appName, appDetails ->
    println "Application: $appName"
    assert appDetails instanceof Map
    appDetails.environments.each { envName, servers ->
        assert servers instanceof List
        println "\tEnvironment: $envName"
        println "\t\t$servers"
    }
}
```

From this code I obtain the following console output.

```
Application: Application1
    Environment: it
        [server1]
    Environment: ft
        [server2]
    Environment: stg
        [server3]
    Environment: prd
        [server4]
Application: Application2
    Environment: it
        [serverA]
    Environment: ft
        [serverB]
    Environment: stg
        [serverC]
    Environment: prd
        [serverD]
```

**EDIT (based on clarification of required output):**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonText = "\n{\n    \"Application1\": {\n    \"environments\": {\n        \"it\": [\n                \"server1\"\n        ],\n        \"ft\": [\n                \"server2\"\n        ],\n        \"stg\": [\n                \"server3\"\n        ],\n        \"prd\": [\n                \"server4\"\n        ]\n    },\n    \"war-path\" : \"/opt/tomcat/\",\n    \"war-name\" : \"Application1\"\n},\n    \"Application2\": {\n    \"environments\": {\n        \"it\": [\n                \"serverA\"\n        ],\n        \"ft\": [\n                \"serverB\"\n        ],\n        \"stg\": [\n                \"serverC\"\n        ],\n        \"prd\": [\n                \"serverD\"\n        ]\n    },\n    \"war-path\" : \"/var/lib\",\n    \"war-name\" : \"Application2\"\n}\n}\n"

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonText)

def result = [:]

jsonMap.each { appName, appDetails ->
    appDetails.environments.each { envName, servers ->
        if ( !result.containsKey(envName) ) {
            result.put(envName, [])
        }
        result.get(envName).addAll(servers)
    }
}
println result
```

Results are a `Map` where the keys are the various environments specified within JSON file, and the values are `List`s of servers associated with those environments across all applications.  You can access any `List` individually with something like `result.stg`, or assign these the different variables later if that's desired/required (`def stg = result.stg`).

```
[it:[server1, serverA], ft:[server2, serverB], stg:[server3, serverC], prd:[server4, serverD]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time answering my query. I updated my expected output. Could you please help ? Also im quite new to Groovy which makes me difficult to understand your answer. Is there any other way this can be programmed ? Thank you already!

Comment: @user1557960, Please see edits based on your clarification of output requirements.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi Phil Wrage, Thanks for all your inputs. It really helped. I have done some small modifications and made it work.

Comment: Updated my answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `environments`, you can use the spread operator to take
all environments from the values.  Next you have to merge the maps on
the keys.  E.g.

```
def json = """ { "Application1": { "environments": { "it": [ "server1" ], "ft": [ "server2" ], "stg": [ "server3" ], "prd": [ "server4" ] }, }, "Application2": { "environments": { "it": [ "serverA" ], "ft": [ "serverB" ], "stg": [ "serverC" ], "prd": [ "serverD" ] }, } } }"""

def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

println data.values()*.environments.inject{ a, b -> 
    b.inject(a.withDefault{[]}) { m, kv -> 
        // with groovy 2.5+: m.tap{ get(kv.key).addAll(kv.value) }
        m[kv.key].addAll(kv.value); m
    } 
}
// → [it:[server1, serverA], ft:[server2, serverB], stg:[server3, serverC], prd:[server4, serverD]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error. "hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.tap() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@5c09fe2e]"

Comment: `tap` is optional here.  I rewrote for old groovy versions